# Loading Haskell Modules that have dependencies

Tags: haskell, import, ghc, ghci

I'm unsure what my issue is here. I have a trio of modules A.hs, B.hs, and C.hs. All are located at `C:\..path...\folder` and modules B and C both import from A.

That is, both modules B and C contain the line `import A`

I can `:l C:\..path..\folder\A.hs` in gchi and play with its contents; however, ghci gives the following error when I try to `:l C:\..path..\folder\B.hs` or `:l C:\..path..\folder\C.hs`

```
    Could not find module `A'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Which I find odd because I had no trouble compiling B.hs to B.exe and running the executable. How can I compile and run a module that I can't load into ghci? Or, why would an import succeed at compile time but fail in loading; especially when that very module being imported is itself load-able?

Comment: I had a similar problem once. If you load the modules on startup (`ghci A.hs B.hs`) does it give an error?

Comment: Hmm, so I tried it and it works with some caveats. If I start up ghci in the order you suggested then ghci makes the claim that both modules

Comment: Hmm, it works with some caveats:

If I start up `ghci A.hs B.hs` then ghci makes the claim that both modules have been loaded, but then when I actually start trying to interact with the contents only functions and types from A.hs are accessible. I get a not-in-scope error for anything in B.hs.

If I exchange the arguments (start up instead as `ghci B.hs A.hs`) I can play with the contents of both. This peculiarity is interesting in it's own right.

Still, the question of understanding why the original approach fails still stands; but, this work-around is appreciated. Thank you @WolfeMacfarlane

Comment: @Tshimanga After running `ghci A.hs B.hs`, you should be able to switch which module is "visible" using `:m`, as in `:m *A` or `:m *B`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `ghci` searches only in the current directory for imported modules. To start with, the current directory is the one used to launch `ghci`; but it can be changed from within `ghci` with the `:cd` command. Thus, you could

```
> :cd C:\...path...\folder
> :l B.hs
```

and this should find both `B.hs` and `A.hs` in what is now the current directory. Alternately (and especially if you have modules in multiple directories) you can launch ghci with the `-i` command line option to add directories to its module search path. For example, in your command prompt you might

```
% ghci -iC:\...path...\folder
> :l B.hs
```

which will instruct `ghci` to include `C:\...path...\folder` in its search path, and therefore find `B.hs` and `A.hs` there even if it is not the current directory.

Comment: Ah, I see. That definitely makes sense. Thanks Daniel